# UIImageView within CollectionView does not update UI after image download

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with a collectionview what should display image thumbnails. The app first needs to download a json string, which contains the url's from which to download the thumbnails.

The problem that I am having is that the collection view cells are not displaying the images, although these are being downloaded by the code.

**Code**

View controller interface:

```
@interface NewsfeedController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rawNewsfeed;
@property NSMutableArray *newsfeedPosts;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *newsfeedCollectionView;

@end
```

The controller's `viewDidLoad` includes the following line:

```
[self.newsfeedCollectionView registerClass:[PostCellView class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCellView"];
```

The cell is a custom cell, as defined by this class:

*PostCellView.h*

```
@interface PostCellView : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *posterImageView;

@end
```

In the view controller, I have implemented the method *cellForItemAtIndexPath* like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PostCellView *postCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCellView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!postCell){
        postCell = [[PostCellView alloc]init];
    }

    long row = indexPath.row;
    PostModel *post = [self.newsfeedPosts objectAtIndex:row];
    NSURL *posterUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:post.media[@"poster"]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *getPosterImage = [[NetworkHelper getInstance].session dataTaskWithURL:posterUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *posterImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            postCell.posterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:posterImage];
        });
    }];
    [getPosterImage resume];

    return postCell;
}
```

As you can see, I am downloading the images for the thumbnails async, so after the download completes, I am trying to update the UI by setting the *posterImageView* within a dispatch_async on the main queue. However, the UI never gets updated with the thumbnails. Looking at the view hierarchy while debugging, the app does create the 8 cells that I am expecting, but again, the images are never displayed.

So, in essence, I cannot make the cells within the collection view of my app display their corresponding images, once those images are downloaded via an async process.

Comment: You shouldn't register the class if you made the cell in the storyboard (or xib). Delete that line.

Comment: As you have registered the class, you will never get `nil` from `dequeueReuseableCell...` - so you can omit that bit.  Have you checked that `postCell.posterImageView` is not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar, I have deleted the line, but still it shows nothing.

Comment: You should give the image view a background color in IB just to make sure the image view is showing up on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar, just did that, and the cells do show up in blue color (the background color I have just configured), but no image is displayed.

Comment: @Paulw11, postCell.posterImageView is not nil, but its parent (postCell) shows up as (null) in the debugger when I set a breakpoint right after             postCell.posterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:posterImage];

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you're alloc init'ing an image view in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. You shouldn't be doing that since you have an IBOutlet to that image view. Just set the image.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment above from rdelmar, the problem was in this line:

```
postCell.posterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:posterImage];
```

I was init'ing an image view that was already declared as an IBOutlet. So I changed that line to this, and the images started appearing:

```
postCell.posterImageView.image = posterImage;
```